# Como puedo obtener la resta de un array en c#

Tags: c#

Si tengo un arreglo con tres valores, después de recorrerlo ¿cómo puedo restar los índices del mismo?

```
int[] valor = { 10, 3, 15 };
int total = 0;
foreach (int i in valores)
{
    // ¿Qué hago aquí?
}
```

Por ejemplo, si tengo un array de 3 números `2, 3, 4` ... lo que quiero restar son los índices

```
2-3-4 = total
```

Comment: a que te refieres con el indice, con el tamaño de el array o restarle el valor de cada uno??

Comment: Creo que se quedo corta la explicacion , te refieres a restarle el indice a cada valor del array?

Comment: si, si tengo un array 3 números 2,3,4 .... lo que quiero restar son los indices 2-3-4 = total ..

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los indices o los valores? los indices de un array son 0,1,2,3...etc dependiendo la cantidad de item del array. Podes dejar claro eso?

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que yo entiendo, lo que necesitás:

Primero que nada, deberías cambiar:

```
foreach (int i in valores)
```

por:

```
foreach (int i in valor)
```

ya que el nombre del array es **valor**

Después, para restar, podrías hacer:

```
int[] valor = { 10, 3, 15 };
        int count = 0;
        int totales = 0;
            foreach(int i in valor){
                if(count==0){
                    totales = i;
                    Console.WriteLine(valor);
                    Console.WriteLine(totales);
                }else{
                    totales = totales - i;
                    Console.WriteLine(totales);
                }
                count++;
            }
        Console.WriteLine(totales);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mismo pero con expresiones lambda, por tener una segunda respuesta:

```
int[] valor = { 10, 3, 15 };
int total = 0;
var lista = valor.ToList();
lista[0] = lista[0] * -1;
valor.ToList().ForEach(v => total = total - v);
```

Se pasa el array a un listado para aprovechar las bondades de ForEach, previamente habiendo cambiado el signo del primer elemento.

Espero que sea de ayuda.